# How to make this entity fieldable?

Tags: 7, entities

I want to make my entity fieldable and manageable from admin area with manage display and manage field admin ui. I have read few tutorials, but I still not understand how to do it? This question is related to my other [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224442/status-entity-what-is-wrong-with-this-code). Here is my entity code.

```
function statuses_entity_info() {
  $backupControl = module_exists('entity') ? 'EntityAPIController' : 'DrupalDefaultEntityController';
  return array(
    'status' => array(
      'label' => t('Status'),
      'plural label' => t('Statuses'),
      'description' => t('A status update.'),
      'entity class' => 'StatusEntity',
      'controller class' => module_exists('statuses') ? 'StatusesEntityController' : $backupControl,
      'base table' => 'statuses',
      'load hook' => 'statuses_load',
      'uri callback' => 'statuses_uri',
      'module' => 'statuses',
      'entity keys' => array(
        'id' => 'sid',
        'label' => 'message',
      ),
       'bundles' => array(
        'status' => array(
          'label' => t('Status'),
        ),
      ),
      'view modes' => array(
        'full' => array(
          'label' => t('Status message'),
          'custom settings' => FALSE,
        ),
      ),
      'entity cache' => FALSE,
    ),
  );
}

function statuses_entity_property_info()  {
  $info = array();

  $info['status']['properties']['sid'] = array(
    'label' => t('Status ID'),
    'description' => t('The ID of the status'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'schema field' => 'sid',
  );

  $info['status']['properties']['sender'] = array(
    'label' => t('Status sender'),
    'description' => t('Sender uid of the status message'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'schema field' => 'sender',
  );
  $info['status']['properties']['recipient'] = array(
    'label' => t('Status recipient'),
    'description' => t('Recipient uid of the status message'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'schema field' => 'recipient',
  );
  $info['status']['properties']['type'] = array(
    'label' => t('Type'),
    'description' => t('Type of status message'),
    'type' => 'text',
    'schema field' => 'type',
  );
  $info['status']['properties']['created'] = array(
    'label' => t('Created'),
    'description' => t('UNIX Timestamp of creation date'),
    'type' => 'integer',
    'schema field' => 'created',
  );
  $info['status']['properties']['message'] = array(
    'label' => t('Message'),
    'description' => t('Status message'),
    'type' => 'text',
    'schema field' => 'message',
  );
  return $info;
}

function statuses_uri($status)  {
  return array(
    'path' => 'statuses/' . $status->sid,
  );
}


class StatusesEntityController extends EntityAPIController  {
//TODO
}


if (class_exists('Entity')) {
  class StatusEntity extends Entity {
    public function __construct(array $values = array(), $entityType = NULL)  {
      parent::__construct($values, 'status');
    }

    public function buildContent($view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
      $content['sender'] = array(
      '#markup' => 'Sender Markup TEST',
      );
      $content['recipient'] = array(
        '#markup' => 'Recipient Markup TEST',
      );
      $content['created'] = array(
        '#markup' => 'Created Markup TEST',
      );
      $content['message'] = array(
        '#markup' => 'Message Markup TEST',
      );
      $content['sid'] = array(
        '#markup' => 'sid Markup TEST',
      );
      $content['type'] = array(
        '#markup' => 'type Markup TEST',
      );
      return entity_get_controller($this->entityType)->buildContent($this, $view_mode, $langcode, $content);


    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `fieldable` key and set it to true:

```
return array(
  'status' => array(
    'label' => t('Status'),
    'plural label' => t('Statuses'),
    'fieldable' => TRUE,
    ...
```

Comment: Will it also add "manage display" and "manage field" links in admin area so that I can add fields to it?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet because I guess I have to uninstall and re-install the module after making changes. That is why I asked.

Comment: Nothing happened

Comment: Yes you might need to reinstall the module. For the field UI there are a few extra steps, see the docs for info: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/field-api/implementing-the-field-management-ui

Comment: Visited the link. The first 2 steps are already there and I am not sure, but I guess I do not need STEP 3, 4. Last step is what I need. which is `function example_edit($example) {
  $build = array();
  field_attach_form('example', $example, $build, $form_state = array());
    return $build;
}

/**
 * Example entity display page.
 */
function example_page($example) {
  $build = array();
  field_attach_prepare_view('example', array($example->example_id => $example), 'full');
  
  return $build;
}`

Comment: Hope I am correct up till now. Okay I have 2 questions. 1. Do I have to replace the word "example" with "statuses" or "status" in above code? 2. Do I have to put this code in .module file? There is a file named statuses.admin.inc located at statuses/includes/utility. This file contains settings shown in admin area